# Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/nuxt-app/nuxt'

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js, circleci

I get  Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/nuxt-app/nuxt' when I try to run app on the server. i didn't change anything in dockerfile or circleci config. it had been working before, i don't know what happened. Image is build by circleci. Locally without using docker everything works as it should. What do I do with it?

Error:

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/nuxt-app/nuxt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add python make g++
ADD . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 5002

CMD [ "nuxt", "start" ]
```

circleci config.yml:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  docker: circleci/docker@1.5.0
  node: circleci/node@4.1.0
workflows:
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy:
          context:
            - docker
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master

jobs:
  deploy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - docker/install-docker-tools
      - run:
          name: Login to Docker
          command: docker login -u=$DOCKER_LOGIN -p=$DOCKER_PASSWORD registry.xxx.com
      - docker/build:
          image: yyy
          registry: registry.xxx.com
          tag: latest
      - docker/push:
          image: yyy
          registry: registry.xxx.com
          tag: latest
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what the solution was?